Difference between a k-parameterized hypergeometric function and its limit when k tends to infinity.
Let's define the following generalized hypergeometric function $f_k(t)={_1F_2\left(1-k;a,2+k;t\right)}$ for $k>0$ and $a>0$.
Then we define $R_k(t) = f_k(t) - \lim\limits_{k \rightarrow\infty} f_k(t) $
Question: is it possible to have another expression for $R_k(t)$ other than its definition, for instance as a serie or an integral (or something else) ?
